# Install Postfix Mail Server

Tags: email, installation, server

Installation for the mail server is successful after executing these commands:

sudo DEBIAN_PRIORITY=low apt install postfix
echo 'export MAIL=~/Maildir' | sudo tee -a /etc/bash.bashrc | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/mail.sh
source /etc/profile.d/mail.sh

but when wanted to check by sending email to my self by this command
echo 'init' | s-nail -s 'init' -Snorecord sammy

when I check maildir
by ls -R ~/Maildir

this dir is empty and doesn't desire output like this:

This is what I expect after ls command

Output
/home/sammy/Maildir/:
cur  new  tmp

/home/sammy/Maildir/cur:

/home/sammy/Maildir/new:
1463177269.Vfd01I40e4dM691221.mail.example.com

/home/sammy/Maildir/tmp: